# paramiko expect timing out

Tags: python, paramiko

Thinking about making a move from Perl to Python running scripts to automate certain tasks on remote servers and devices. We need to be able to use Expect to check for certain results and get the data back. Taking a look at Paramiko-Expect and I like it, but it's timing out every time.

```
import paramiko
from paramikoe import SSHClientInteraction

HOSTNAME = "HOST IP"
PASSWORD = "PWORD"
USERNAME = "UNAME"
PROMPT = "(node name)#"

command = "show command"

print PROMPT

file = open("testlog.txt","w")

def main():

    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect(HOSTNAME, port=22, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)

    interact = SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=10, display=True)

    interact.send(command)
    interact.expect(PROMPT)
    file.write(interact.current_output_clean)
    client.close()

    return



main()
file.close()
```

This is the traceback I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
 File "python_test.py", line 40, in <module> 
  main()    
 File "python_test.py", line 28, in main 
  interact.expect(PROMPT)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramikoe.py", line 122, in expect 
  buffer = self.channel.recv(self.buffer_size)    
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 598, in recv 
  raise socket.timeout() socket.timeout
```

I've tried multiple versions of the PROMPT to expect, from directly putting in the text of the node I'm trying it on to full regex. Nothing works. It always times out when it gets to the client.expect. Paramiko-expect documentation does not help and the only other place I see this question is different enough that it doesn't help.
Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put prompt to something you expect, as... prompt. [Here](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect/blob/master/examples/paramiko_expect-demo.py) is paramiko interaction example. Please note lines 21, and 37 -

```
PROMPT = 'vagrant@paramiko-expect-dev:~\$\s+'

interact.expect(PROMPT)
```

So, when I've updated part of your code to:

```
interact = SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=10, display=True)
interact.expect(PROMPT)

interact.send("ls")
interact.expect(".*Maildir.*")
file.write(interact.current_output_clean)
client.close()
```

I have `testlog.txt` filled with listing of the home directory, of remote host.

As a side note - switch to python 3. If you are starting, it is better to use tool that is not well known to be outdated soon. Also you can use ipython, or jupyter - code will be more interactive, faster to test. Maybe [netmiko](https://github.com/ktbyers/netmiko) will be interested for you?

Comment: I just put PROMPT = "(node name)#" as an example of what I'm entering for the prompt. I've used regex in there and set it to the exact prompt that it should be seeing and I get the timeout either way.

I will look into netmiko.

Comment: I mean that I set it to a regex and also tried setting it to the exact prompt, like you did. So I'm really at a loss as to why it's working for you but not me. It appears to not be the code, though, so I will look for other solutions.

Comment: See your point - I've used `username@host:~\$\s+` as in the example + checked before send, and after send used one of the entries... Maybe use `.*` to get it all,to see what is there?

Comment: So apparently this was the correct answer. I tried a lot of things and went back to my original code and added \s+ to the end of my regex and it worked. Where is the facepalm emoticon on stackoverflow?